# Qt QChart Multithread error

Tags: c++, qt

En este ejemplo de código se crean dos botones: el primero muestra una gráfica en una nueva ventana, el segundo imprime una gráfica en otro hilo para hacer un uso concurrente y no gastar el hilo principal (no es el caso del ejemplo pero podría demorar mucho en generar los datos de la gráfica) .

La cuestión es que en la misma ejecución podemos hacer uso del primer botón o del segundo repetidamente sin ningún problema, pero si los alternamos producimos un error. A pesar de instanciar el objeto independientemente a cada botón y tener un alcance local del mismo se produce el error:

```
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QTextDocument(0x562988b91200),
parent's thread is QThread(0x562987bc9810),
current thread is QThread(0x562987e68ac0))
```

¿Alguien sabe como solucionarlo?

```cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QtConcurrent/QtConcurrent>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QChartView>
#include <QLineSeries>
#include <QValueAxis>
#include <QChart>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QPrintEngine>

class ChartWidget : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ChartWidget(QWidget *parent = nullptr) : QWidget(parent) {
        QtCharts::QChart *chart = new QtCharts::QChart;
        QtCharts::QLineSeries *series = new QtCharts::QLineSeries;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
            series->append(i, qrand() % 100);

        chart->addSeries(series);

        QtCharts::QValueAxis *axisX = new QtCharts::QValueAxis;
        QtCharts::QValueAxis *axisY = new QtCharts::QValueAxis;
        chart->addAxis(axisX, Qt::AlignBottom);
        chart->addAxis(axisY, Qt::AlignLeft);
        series->attachAxis(axisX);
        series->attachAxis(axisY);

        QtCharts::QChartView *chartView = new QtCharts::QChartView(chart);
        QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout;
        layout->addWidget(chartView);
        setLayout(layout);
    }
    ~ChartWidget() {
        close();
    }
    void printChart() {
        QPrinter *Printer=new QPrinter();
        QPainter *Painter=new QPainter();
        Printer->setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
        Printer->setOutputFileName("/tmp/test.pdf");
        Painter->begin(Printer);
        this->render(Painter);
        Painter->end();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QPushButton *button1=new QPushButton("Main Th");
    QPushButton *button2=new QPushButton("Concurrent Th");

    QWidget *window=new QWidget;
    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
    layout->addWidget(button1);
    layout->addWidget(button2);
    window->setLayout(layout);
    window->show();


    QObject::connect(button1, &QPushButton::clicked, []() {
        ChartWidget *W=new ChartWidget();
        W->show();
    });

    QObject::connect(button2, &QPushButton::clicked, []() {

        QtConcurrent::run([](){
            ChartWidget *W=new ChartWidget();
            W->printChart();
        });

    });

    return app.exec();

}

#include "main.moc"
```

Parece que realmente el problema esta en el QChartView, en este simple ejemplo se puede ver el error como una advertencia:

```cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtConcurrent/QtConcurrent>
#include <QChartView>
#include <QChart>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QtConcurrent::run([](){
        QtCharts::QChartView Plot;
    });

    QWidget MyWindow;
    MyWindow.show();

    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

¿Se puede usar el QChart sin el QChartView?

Comment: No soy un experto en QT, pero en multihilos en general, la parte visual suele no ser _thread safe_, por lo que la creación y actualización de controles se lleva a cabo solo desde el hilo principal o se tienen las consideraciones que requiere la biblioteca visual para poder trabajar con ella desde hilos secundarios. QT no parece ser la excepción, mira el punto 2 del artículo [The Eight Rules of Multithreaded Qt](https://www.kdab.com/the-eight-rules-of-multithreaded-qt/), titulado _Never do GUI operations off the main thread_.

Comment: Gracias Jachguate por tu tiempo. La verdad es que en mi aplicación de producción la necesidad de concurrencia viene al imprimir una gráfica, así que teóricamente no hay interacción en la GUI . El ejemplo expuesto es una simplificación para poder reproducir el error. Parece que el objeto QChart hereda otros que dificultan mi propuesta, de echo el error lo produce un QTextDocument.

Answer (score 0):

`QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread` Esto ocurre cuando se intenta crear un objeto hijo en un threads diferente al del objeto padre.

Observa que aquí el objeto padre es el botón.

```
QPushButton *button2=new QPushButton("Concurrent Th");
```

Este es el objeto hijo, ChartWidget.

```
QtConcurrent::run({
ChartWidget *W=new ChartWidget();
W->printChart();
});
```

Si se cambia el objeto ChartWidget a la hebra principal, podría resolver el problema.

**Qt** siempre evitará que cualquier objeto de la interfaz gráfica sea manipulado por hilos distintos a aquel en el que fue creado.

```
    //... Código previo no modificado.
    
   int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QPushButton *button1=new QPushButton("Main Th");
    QPushButton *button2=new QPushButton("Concurrent Th");

    QWidget *window=new QWidget;
    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
    layout->addWidget(button1);
    layout->addWidget(button2);
    window->setLayout(layout);
    window->show();


    QObject::connect(button1, &QPushButton::clicked, []() {
        ChartWidget *W=new ChartWidget();
        W->show();
    });

     /*El objeto hijo es creado en el hilo principal.*/
    QtConcurrent::run([](){
        ChartWidget *W=new ChartWidget();
        W->printChart();
    });

    return app.exec();

}

#include "main.moc"
```

Puedes usar `QtConcurrent::mapped()`, que creará dos objetos ChartWidget en hilos separados de esta manera manteniendo la funcionalidad de los dos botones.

```
//Código previo no modificado.
 int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QPushButton *button1=new QPushButton("Main Th");
    QPushButton *button2=new QPushButton("Concurrent Th");

    QWidget *window=new QWidget;
    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
    layout->addWidget(button1);
    layout->addWidget(button2);
    window->setLayout(layout);
    window->show();


    QObject::connect(button1, &QPushButton::clicked, []() {
        ChartWidget *W=new ChartWidget();
        W->show();
    });

    /* Los objetos secundarios de ChartWidget se crearán en threads separados a partir de ahora. */
    QtConcurrent::mapped([&](){
        ChartWidget *W=new ChartWidget();
        W->printChart();
    }, 2);

    return app.exec();

}

#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: Gracias Cardosource por tu tiempo. La verdad que no soy capaz de compilar tu ejemplo (Al menos en mi Qt 5.12), de todas maneras las funciones QtConcurrent::map() entiendo que son para procesar paralelamente una lista de objetos, no acabo de entender tu propuesta.